# HashMap is not synchronized then why concurrentmodification exception

Tags: java, hashmap, iterator, concurrenthashmap

HashMap is not supposed to be thread safe, then why do the iterators throw `concurrentmodificationexception` if someone has modified the hashMap.

Also ConcurrentHashMap does not throw this exception.

Is Iterator implementation different for different datastructures or there is someone method within these data structures which throw `ConcurrentModificationException`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the structure of a `HashMap` is modified (i.e. entries are added or removed) while the `HashMap` is being iterated over, the iterator may fail in many ways.

The `ConcurrentModificationException` exception is meant to make any iterators fail-fast as a result of such modifications.

That's what the `modCount` field is for :

```
/**
 * The number of times this HashMap has been structurally modified
 * Structural modifications are those that change the number of mappings in
 * the HashMap or otherwise modify its internal structure (e.g.,
 * rehash).  This field is used to make iterators on Collection-views of
 * the HashMap fail-fast.  (See ConcurrentModificationException).
 */
transient int modCount;
```

This behavior is not specific to `Map`s. `Collection`s also throw this exception when they are being modified during iteration.

Answer (score 3):

Don't be fooled into thinking that `Concurrent` relates solely to multi-threading.

The exception means that the collection was structurally modified whilst you are using an iterator created before the modification. That modification *might* be performed by a different thread, but it could be the same thread as the one doing the iteration.

The following single-threaded code yields a CME:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("a", "a");
map.put("b", "b");

for (String k: map.entrySet()) {
  map.clear();
}
```

Or, showing the iterator in the loop more clearly (the two loops are equivalent):

```
Iterator<String> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  String k = it.next();
  map.clear();
}
```

`it.hasNext()` is called after `map.clear()`, resulting in a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is Iterator implementation different for different datastructures or
>   there is someone method within these data structures which throw
>   ConcurrentModificationException ?

Yes, **there are different `Iterator` implementations** inside `Collection` classes.

For example, **`HashMap` class (uses `HashIterator` internally), `ConcurrentHashMap` (uses `KeyIterator`, `ValueIterator`, etc.. internally)**, `ArrayList` (uses `Iterator` from `AbstractList`), etc..

**HashMap's Iterator is different from ConcurrentHashMap's Iterator implementation.**

HashMap's Iterator maintain a version number (`expectedModCount`) and verify `checkForComodification()` as shown below:

```
final void checkForComodification() {
   if (modCount != expectedModCount)
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
}
```

So, in the middle of the iteration, if the underlying collection size is modified (by adding/removing the elements), then the `Iterator` throw `ConcurrentModificationException` as shown above.

Where as `ConcurrentHashMap`'s `Iterator` implementations does not perform the above check, so it does not throw the `ConcurrentModificationException`. You can also find the same point from API the `ConcurrentHashMap` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

> They **(ConcurrentHashMaps)** do not throw ConcurrentModificationException. However, iterators
>   are designed to be used by only one thread at a time.

Answer (score 0):

As the HashMap is a fail-fast Collection (All the collections under java.util package are fail fast), Iterator Throws exception if any modification is done to the structure or the keys majorly in case of Hashmap.

we have a variable in Hashmap that count the number of Modifications in the Map.and using that iterator keeps the track of the no of modifications done on the Collection.

```
transient volatile int modCount;
```

Please read the below link: the Difference is explained very well:
[Java Modcount (ArrayList)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668901/java-modcount-arraylist)
Good Example:
http://www.journaldev.com/122/java-concurrenthashmap-example-iterator