# Why does the set method in ArrayList not update the modCount?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

The modCount tracks how many times was the list changed.
Then why does set method not update it ? 
Here is a reference from JDK 1.7

```
   public E set(int index, E element) {
    rangeCheck(index);

    E oldValue = elementData(index);
    elementData[index] = element;
    return oldValue;
}
```

EDIT: If this concept had not been in place and we remove from/ modify the list, the loops will not error out. The goal of this concept is to enforce the Single Responsibility Principle to the loop and prevent the users from making crimes which they might not realize ?

Answer (score 1):

The [description of the field is](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#modCount):

> The number of times this list has been structurally modified. Structural modifications are those that change the size of the list, or otherwise perturb it in such a fashion that iterations in progress may yield incorrect results.

Changing an *existing* slot in the list doesn't cause a structural change. In other words, it doesn't mess with existing iterators like adding or removing would.

Answer (score 0):

In short - it doesn't counts changes in existing nodes but counts their amount change operations (those after which list.size() invocation will show different result).

In long - see [Java Modcount (ArrayList)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668901/java-modcount-arraylist)